# I'm trying to send requests to servers

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cvidyasharam.physicscafe.in/loginmobile.php?email=%@ password=%@",Username.text,Password.text];
equest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
   responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

}

if  ([responseData isEqual:@"yes"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"condition" sender:nil];
    login = @1;
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incorrect combo" message:@"Intruder alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
```

Every time I run the program it ends with the screen highlighting the 
 responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
 line in green.
Is anything wrong with the code?

Comment: try setting your err and response to nil. Can you provide the messages printed to your console.

Comment: it highlights the responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
line in green and says thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 in the background.
It does the same for 14 other lines throughout the program.
the rest of them were present by default.
the emulator is frozen or something..
can't add pictures.

Comment: put the image in dropbox or flicker and post the link here

Comment: [link]https://www.flickr.com/photos/129394209@N03/

Comment: Stupid question:  Do you have a breakpoint set on that line?  (Little circle thing in the left-hand margin.)

Comment: umm nope.
is it necessary?

Comment: It seems like you're stopped at a breakpoint, since there's no indication of an exception.  But if you say you don't have a breakpoint set then I suppose we must believe you.

Comment: Arjun if possible post your project.

Comment: I had a breakpoint there
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @HotLicks said is true.

The application has stopped on a break point.

My statement based on the images you provided here. Take a closer look.

[image]

It clearly shows that the execution has been **paused**.  See if you have something like this on that particular line.

[image]

Delete it like this

[image]

You can read more about it here. http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: thanks.
It worked.
I got the wrong idea when hot licks said "little circle thing on left hand margin"